# How to use org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager in an eclipse-rcp application?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, eclipse-rcp, log4j2

I am trying to use the log4j2 LogManager in an eclipse rcp application.
I have

> -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager

set as start parameter. Starting the rcp application from within my eclipse IDE everything works as expected. But as soon as I start it as a standalone application logging won't work.

A possible hint may be the following stacktrace from the client console:

```
Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder.loadClass(ContextFinder.java:131)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.threadio.ThreadIOImpl.<clinit>(ThreadIOImpl.java:30)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.activator.Activator.start(Activator.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.console.command.adapter.Activator.startBundle(Activator.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.console.command.adapter.Activator.start(Activator.java:237)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:215)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

What do I need to do to get logging running in the RCP application without starting it from within my IDE?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like eclipse is aware of your dependency on this class and is able to add it to the classpath for you. What you need is a way to add the dependency to the classpath when you run it outside of eclipse. To fix this, ensure the class `org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager` is on the classpath. This can be done with -cp and the path to the jar file. For example if you have a class com.org.Main you are trying to run.

```
java -cp your.jar:log4j-jul-2.3.jar com.org.Main
```

your.jar is the jar containing your application and log4j-jul-2.3.jar is the jar containing the missing class.